# Searchable OCR of PDF documents on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

Does Windows Server 2012 support OCR-ing of PDF documents, so that Windows users connected to a shared disk on the Windows Server can use the built-in search functionality in Windows Explorer to find PDFs containing certain words?

Alternatively, if there are plug-ins or 3rd party solutions that enable this?

Answer (score 0):

I did not test with 2012 but in 2008R2, you want to make sure you have a program like Adobe Reader installed so that the IFilter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter) for PDF is installed. Then you just need to enable indexing.

Answer (score 0):

No. The MODI library has an old version of built in OCR, but it can only be used by referencing the library in Code. For complex documents you would not want to use it anyway.  Adobe also licenses the same engine.  The best thing to do is to get a copy of Nuance or FineReader, which both have a corporate edition you can setup on the server with a "Hot Folder" so all images or non-searchable PDF will be automatically converted then transferred to the location of your choice. And because Nuance and ABBYY make up 95% of all the OCR out there, you are not getting it through a third party like Adobe for a premium.